# How to detect which imageview was selected/clicked when clicking another button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am trying to make a program where there are 3 imageviews, 2 buttons named flip and rotate, and a directional pad. The thing I haven't figured out is how to save which imageview was clicked, so currently only a specific one works.

Here is my mainactivity.java:

```
package com.mdadi.animals;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView cat = findViewById(R.id.cat);
    int tenDpAsPx = (int) 
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, 
getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bird:
            findViewById(R.id.bird_desc).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Cat & Dog TextViews set to invisible
            findViewById(R.id.cat_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.dog_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.cat:
            findViewById(R.id.cat_desc).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Bird & Dog TextViews set to invisible
            findViewById(R.id.bird_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.dog_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.dog:
            findViewById(R.id.dog_desc).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Bird & Cat TextViews set to invisible
            findViewById(R.id.bird_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.cat_desc).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //Check which button is clicked and execute relevant code
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.centerBtn: //Reset ImgView translation to original position
            cat.setTranslationX(0);
            cat.setTranslationY(0);
            break;
        case R.id.upArrow: //Move ImgView up ^
            cat.setTranslationY(cat.getTranslationY() - tenDpAsPx);
            break;
        case R.id.downArrow: //Move ImgView down v
            cat.setTranslationY(cat.getTranslationY() + tenDpAsPx);
            break;
        case R.id.leftArrow: //Move ImgView to the left <-
            cat.setTranslationX(cat.getTranslationX() - tenDpAsPx);
            break;
        case R.id.rightArrow: //Move ImgView to the right ->
            cat.setTranslationX(cat.getTranslationX() + tenDpAsPx);
            break;
        case R.id.rotateBtn: //Rotate ImgView 90 degrees clockwise
            cat.setRotation(cat.getRotation() + 90);
            break;
        case R.id.flipBtn: //Flip ImgView about its y axis (horizontally)
            cat.setRotationY(cat.getRotationY() + 180);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

activity_main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rotateBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/rotate_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/flipBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rotateBtn"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/flip_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/centerBtn"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/downArrow"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rightArrow"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_center_focus_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/leftArrow"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerBtn"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/rightArrow"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/upArrow"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/centerBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_upward_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/downArrow"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bird"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/bird" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bird"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/cat" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/dog" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bird_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bird"
    android:text="@string/bird"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bird"
    android:text="@string/cat"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dog_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
    android:text="@string/dog"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How would I go about saving which imgview was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Make your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="3dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="myfunction"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So i guess you just want to track which `imageView` was clicked. So for that, what you can do is create an integer value and then store the index of the image over there.

For example, if you have 3 images then:

```
public void myfunction(View view){
  switch(view.getParent()){
//tells you which linearlayout was clicked
}
}
```

You can track later which image was clicked by accessing this variable.
Also if you want to even keep the track of the images being clicked then you can use an `ArrayList` of `Integer` and then just keep adding the values there.

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a `int` named `selectedImage` and each time you click on an image you give a value to `selectedImage` exemple : 
When image one is clicked `selectedImage = 1`. 
And in your code check the value of `selectedImage` and do the job for the adequate image

Answer (score 0):

To detect imageview on button click add selected imageviews in arraylist and on button click get all imageview id and tag from arraylist like this:

**Code**

***Add views on imageclick***

```
 case R.id.img_2:
            if (!imgviewlist.contains(img_2)) {
                imgviewlist.add(img_2);
            }
            break;
```

***getviews on button click***

```
  case R.id.btn_1:
            /*get selected images form array*/
            for (int j = 0; j < imgviewlist.size(); j++) {
                ImageView imageView = imgviewlist.get(j);
                Log.e("get_imageview_id", "" + imageView.getId());
                Log.e("get_imageview_tag", "" + imageView.getTag());
            }
            break;
```

**Full Code**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn_1;
ImageView img_3, img_2, img_1;
ArrayList<ImageView> imgviewlist = new ArrayList<>();

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    /*intilize views*/
    btn_1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    img_3 = findViewById(R.id.img_3);
    img_2 = findViewById(R.id.img_2);
    img_1 = findViewById(R.id.img_1);
    /*set on click listener*/
    btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_3.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_2.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_1.setOnClickListener(this);

    /*set tag*/
    img_1.setTag("img_1");
    img_2.setTag("img_2");
    img_3.setTag("img_3");

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_1:
            /*get selected images form array*/
            for (int j = 0; j < imgviewlist.size(); j++) {
                ImageView imageView = imgviewlist.get(j);
                Log.e("get_imageview_id", "" + imageView.getId());
                Log.e("get_imageview_tag", "" + imageView.getTag());
            }
            break;
        case R.id.img_1:
            //check item already exist or not
            if (!imgviewlist.contains(img_1)) {
                imgviewlist.add(img_1);  //add imageview in array
            }

            break;
        case R.id.img_2:
            if (!imgviewlist.contains(img_2)) {
                imgviewlist.add(img_2);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.img_3:
            if (!imgviewlist.contains(img_3)) {
                imgviewlist.add(img_3);
            }
            break;

    }
}
 }
```